# Dynamically create any number of sequentially firing functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sequential

(JavaScript) I have a function that deals player cards in a nice sequential fashion: Player, Dealer, Player, Dealer. Below is that part of the function which sequentially moves cards to the viewport.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    player1.style.top = `70%`;
    player1.style.left = `30%`;
    player1.style.transform = `rotate(${Math.floor(Math.random() * rotationMax)}deg)`;
    setTimeout(() => {
        dealer1.style.top = `8%`;
        dealer1.style.left = `30%` 
        dealer1.style.transform = `rotate(${Math.floor(Math.random() * rotationMax)+1}deg)`;
        setTimeout(() => {
            player2.style.top = `70%`;
            player2.style.left = `50%`
            player2.style.transform = `rotate(${Math.floor(Math.random() * rotationMax)}deg)`;
            setTimeout(() => {
                flippedCard.style.top = '8%';
                flippedCard.style.left = '44%';
            
        }, 200)}, 200)}, 100)}, 200)
```

You can see that this block works only with a set number of cards (in this case 4). I am not yet good enough in Javascript to create function that would dynamically generate any number of cards to be dealt.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Specific question: how do you dynamically generate tasks that run one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of dealer cards and player cards, and figure out the differences in the `left` you want for each. Then iterate over the arrays, delaying with `await` to make the code flat and readable:

```
const delay200 = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200);
const playerCards = [player1, player2];
const dealerCards = [dealer1, dealer2];
const playerLeftIncrement = 20; // eg: 30%, then 50%, then 70%; adjust as needed
const dealerLeftIncrement = 14; // eg: 30%, then 44%, then 58%; adjust as needed
const applyStyle = (card, left) => {
  Object.assign(
    card.style,
    {
      top: '70%',
      left,
      transform: `rotate(${Math.floor(Math.random() * rotationMax)}deg)`,
    }
  );
};
for (let i = 0; i < playerCards.length; i++) {
  applyStyle(playerCards[i], `${30 + i * playerLeftIncrement}%`);
  await delay200();
  applyStyle(dealerCards[i], `${30 + i * dealerLeftIncrement}%`);
  await delay200();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to have a function that looks something like:
`callFunctionsWithDelays(functions, delays)`

That would avoid the nested look to your code, and make it easy to dynamically generate. I'd write this using async/await syntax:

```
async function callFunctionsWithDelays(functions, delays) {
    for (i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
         functions[i].call()
         await new Promise(resolve, setTimeout(resolve, delays[i]))
    }
}
```